# How to not be forced to add AuthenticationSchemes on actions' [Authorize] attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a beginner to ASP.NET Core, specifically ASP.NET Core 6.0. I tried following tutorials to set up Identity + JWT authentication and authorization in my current Web API (*not minimal*) project, and though it works so far with basic login/register, there's one thing bothering me that I haven't found an answer to, in the tutorials or on any SO question.

I have to add `AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to the `[Authorize(...)]` attribute on every controller action, otherwise they all return a 404 empty result, even with correct authentication + authorization (if any).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using FluentValidation;

using Capstone.ExceptionHandling;
using Capstone.Data;
using Capstone.Models;
using Capstone.Features;
using Capstone.Features.ApplicantModule;
using Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Capstone.Features.Auth;
using Capstone.Features.Auth.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// ... irrelevant

// ---- Auth ----
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidIssuer").Value,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudience").Value,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:SecretKey").Value
            ))
        };
    });
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<AuthUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CapstoneContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IValidator<RegisterRequest>, RegisterRequestValidator>();

// ... irrelevant

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("Capstone");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Is there a way to set this globally in my project?**

I've tried multiple fixes suggested online, like manually setting `AddAuthentication` options (`DefaultScheme, DefaultAuthenticationScheme, DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`) rather than just passing `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, and checking my ordering of `Use...` calls, such as guaranteeing `UseAuthentication` goes before `UseAuthorization`, though these usually mention `UseRouting` or `UseMvc` but my project doesn't have those.

I simply want to not have to supply the `AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` in `[Authorize(...)]` attributes on controllers' action methods.

Comment: Have you overriden the default authorization policy by any chance?

Comment: And while I'm at it: Did you call `builder.Services.AddAuthorization()`? Just ticking boxes to narrow down possible solutions.

Comment: @Marco Check the AddAuthentication() call in my `Program.cs`. I passed a lambda that sets `DefaultScheme`, `DefaultAuthenticationScheme`, `DefaultChallengeScheme` each to `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, which is one of the fixes suggested by answers I've found. But I still have to manually pass `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBeareDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ...<other params here such as Roles>)]` on top of my controllers' action methods. Otherwise, I'd get a 404 response every time, even with the proper `Authorization: Bearer <token>` headers.

Comment: That is not what I've asked. Read again: Did you call `builder.Services.Add**Authorization**`? If so, please add it to your code.

Comment: @Marco Sorry, that 2nd reply didn't show up until I posted the comment. I did not. But I did try adding it, without any options as I don't know what they do, and then remove `AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` in the [Authorize()] attribute. It still caused the 404 responses.
Just as a note, I've added *all* that might relate to auth/Identity/JWT in my `Program.cs` file. The rest are definitely unrelated (my own services for business logic or validations).

Comment: How about adding AddAuthorization and keeping the defaultScheme? After all, the Authorization system does need to know, what is the default scheme.

Comment: @Marco I did that. I kept my `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {...})` call the same (sets `DefaultScheme`, `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` and `DefaultChallengeScheme` to `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`). I then added `builder.Services.AddAuthorization()` **with no lambas for customizing options** right below. Still responds with 404 for every request, regardless of token (valid, invalid, missing token).

Comment: Alright, I'll try to reproduce the issue locally. If you can provide a reproducible example as a git repo, that would be great

Comment: @Marco Here's my current repo (somewhat cluttered, but still fairly easy to navigate I hope, sorry I can't get a cleaner repo): https://github.com/Utsuhoagie/Capstone-Project-Server/tree/Repro-AuthorizeAttribute
I think any problems should be in `Program.cs`, `Features/Auth/Auth<Controller or Service>.cs`, and the example route I'm using to test is `Features/Applicant/ApplicantsController.cs`' `GetApplicants()` method, at `/api/Applicants` with no query params. I've tried multiple combinations of fixes and toggling that method's `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = ..., Roles(...)]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and a workaround, but I don't know what's really causing it.

When looking at the console, after issuing a request you can see this:

> dbug:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
> AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

And this was my initial suspicion: There is another default handler configured.

If you look at the source of `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` you will see the following code:

```cs
// Services used by identity
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
    };
})
/*...*/
```

This configures Cookies as the default. I've tried to put the Jwt configuration behind it, to no avail. The cookie stayed the default implementation.

But I could still configure the Bearer scheme as the default authorization policy:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthorization(opt =>
    {
        // Configure the default policy
        opt.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

This adds a global policy, that will require each request to pass this policy. So you don't need to add an `[Authorize]` attribute anywhere any more. Just put an `[AllowAnonymous]` above your `AuthController`, so people can still register.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still need `[Authorize(Roles = /* my roles */)]`, so I *can't* simply remove the attribute altogether. Also, I tried this, but it still returns 404 for every response.

Comment: I've used your code. You must be doing something different.

Comment: That's weird, the latest commit on my repro branch is the exact same as my local. 
I've tried moving the `AddIdentity()` call to *before* `AddAuthentication()` like you said you did, but *without* your `opt.DefaultPolicy` fix in this answer, and that worked for me. I can add only `[Authorize(Roles = ...)]` and it works, for all 3 cases (unauthenticated, authenticated but not authorized, and both authenticated & authorized)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the order in which authentication is added, and the authentication method added later will overwrite the first addition. If Bearer is added before Identity, the default AuthenticationSchemes will be Identity. In this case, if you want to use Bearer, you need to specify it.